# React Native Bullet Character? or Unicode?

Tags: react-native, unicode, expo, bulletedlist

I want to use Bullet Character/ Small Circles used for passwords in React Native Text component. Is there a way to create them without using package.

[image]

I am thinking of creating a rounded View with background filled. However, kindly let know if a simpler solution exists.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

There is a much simpler way,

Try using Unicode.

2B24, 25CF, 26AB, etc... these are Unicode for black filled dots.

**USAGE**: `<Text>{'\u2B24'}</Text>`.

You can search more Unicode here, http://www.unicode.org/

Answer (score 3):

If you're wanting to create a TextInput that obscures the entries (e.g. for a password input), TextInput has a [secureTextEntry](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#securetextentry) prop.