# How to Use Unicode While Array Map in JSX REACT?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unicode, jsx

```
const data = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"] // example data
const unicode = &bull; // This is the unicode that I want to put in the jsx
<div>
{
data.map((item)=>(
    item + <span>unicode</span>
))
}
</div>
```

But doesn't work it displays [object Object]

I Tried `(&bull;)` , `{"&bull;"}`, `<span>&bull;</span>`, `<span>{"&bull;"}</span>`

but none of them worked.

Any idea how I can use it unicode elements in JSX while mapping array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [React Native Bullet Character? or Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55448270) (You just need to remove the `<Text>` wrapper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `8226` code instead of `&bull;`. I got this code from https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/punctuation/bullet/

Also, your JSX syntax is not correct.

```
import React from "react";

function App() {
    const data = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"] // example data
    const unicode = 8226; // unicode equivalent to &bull;

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <div>
        {
            data.map((item)=>(
                <>{item} <span>{String.fromCharCode(unicode)}</span></>
            ))
        }
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is an example code which works as expected.

Comment: There's no need whatsoever to go through `String.fromCharCode` for this.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I agree. This can be optimised. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

"Unicode" and *Named HTML Character Entities* aren't the same thing. `&bull;` is a named character entity for Unicode code point [U+2022](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=2022). To write a unicode code point in JavaScript (for instance, in a string you're going to use later), you can use a Unicode code unit escape (`\u2022`) if it fits in one unit (or a pair of them if you want to manually write a surrogate pair), or a Unicode code *point* escape for any Unicode code point (`\u{2022}`).

Separately, JSX fragments aren't *strings*, you can't concatenate them with `+`. To write a series of fragments all together, you can wrap them in a `<React.Fragment>___</React.Fragment>` (more commonly, the shorthand: `<>___</>`).

Here's an example making `unicode` a string:

```
const data = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
const unicode = "\u{2022}";
return (
    <div>
        {data.map((item) => (
            <>
                {item}<span>{unicode}</span>
            </>
        ))}
    </div>
);
```

```js
const Example = () => {
    const data = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
    const unicode = "\u{2022}";
    return (
        <div>
            {data.map((item) => (
                <React.Fragment>
                    {item}<span>{unicode}</span>
                </React.Fragment>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Here's an example making `unicode` a fragment around `&bull;`:

```
const data = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
const unicode = <>&bull;</>;
return (
    <div>
        {data.map((item) => (
            <React.Fragment>
                {item}<span>{unicode}</span>
            </React.Fragment>
        ))}
    </div>
);
```

```js
const Example = () => {
    const data = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
    const unicode = <React.Fragment>&bull;</React.Fragment>;
    return (
        <div>
            {data.map((item) => (
                <React.Fragment>
                    {item}<span>{unicode}</span>
                </React.Fragment>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

---

Note: The Stack Snippets above use the long form of React.Fragment because the version of Babel in Stack Snippets is ***so old*** it doesn't understand the shorthand syntax. One of [many problems with Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400732/please-fix-stack-snippets) that SE Inc. has been ignoring for years.